# Error: expected class,delegate,enum,interface or struct

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, syntax-error

I get the following error on the code below:

> expected class,delegate,enum,interface or struct.

This happens when hovering on **GH_ObjectResponse**, what am I doing wrong?

```
public class SettingsComponentAttributes : GH_ComponentAttributes
{
    public SettingsComponentAttributes(IGH_Component SettingsComponent) :  
        base(SettingsComponent) {}
}

public override GH_ObjectResponse RespondToMouseDoubleClick(
    GH_Canvas sender, GH_CanvasMouseEvent e)
{
    ((SettingsComponent)Owner).ShowSettingsGui();
    return GH_ObjectResponse.Handled;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your method is not declared inside the class... try this instead:

```
public class SettingsComponentAttributes : GH_ComponentAttributes
{
    public SettingsComponentAttributes(IGH_Component SettingsComponent) : base(SettingsComponent) { }

    public override GH_ObjectResponse RespondToMouseDoubleClick(GH_Canvas sender, GH_CanvasMouseEvent e)
    {
        ((SettingsComponent)Owner).ShowSettingsGui();
        return GH_ObjectResponse.Handled;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Watch your brackets.  It should be:

```
public class SettingsComponentAttributes : GH_ComponentAttributes
{
    public SettingsComponentAttributes(IGH_Component SettingsComponent) : base(SettingsComponent) {}

    public override GH_ObjectResponse RespondToMouseDoubleClick(GH_Canvas sender, GH_CanvasMouseEvent e)
    {
        ((SettingsComponent)Owner).ShowSettingsGui();
        return GH_ObjectResponse.Handled;
    }
}
```